# Python: Read multiple excel sheets, add column and append it to one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a All Fields Data frame with all the columns(headers) in it.

I have to read a excel workbook which have 25 sheets but i only have to read 10 sheets out of it. So i am passing the list of the files in a nested for loop to read the sheets and name of the sheets are like "Labour M1","Travel M1","Equip M1"..... "Labour M2","Travel M2"etc.

I have one main loop which defines the variable for the number at the end of the sheet name.

So i am reading all the sheets with 1 at the last and saving it in a list and then appending to Dataframe1, then adding a column with name "Milestone" which will have the value of "i" in main for loop and then it loop again and read the the sheets which have 2 number at the last and then same process.

So finally i am appending "Dataframe1" to "Allfields" dataframe and then i am saving that "Allfields" dataframe to excel file after finishing the loop.

So when i open the excel file it appended the data correctly but problem is the column which i am adding it takes always takes the last value of "i" in a for loop but it should take the value of number which i am reading.

Here is my code

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    list_sheets = ['Labour M' + str(i), 'Travel M' + str(i), 'Equip M' + str(i), 'Consult-SubC M' + str(i),
                   'Other M' + str(i)]
    Empty_List = []

    All_Milestone = pd.DataFrame()
    for p in list_sheets:

        print(p)
        book_open = open_workbook(getpath())

        sheet_open = book_open.sheet_by_name(p)

        print("Successfully found the sheet")

        for rowidx in range(sheet_open.nrows):
            row = sheet_open.row(rowidx)
            for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell.value == "Consortium Member":
                    print("Sheet Name:", sheet_open.name)
                    print("Row Number:", rowidx)
                    value = int(rowidx)
        else:
            print("Sheet ", sheet_open, "not found.")

        reading_book = pd.read_excel(getpath(), sheet_name=p, skiprows=value)
        sheet = reading_book.dropna(axis=0, how='any', subset=['Consortium Member'])
        sheet.drop([col for col in sheet.columns if "Unnamed" in col], axis=1, inplace=True)

        print("Successfully read the sheet" + p + "\n")

        Empty_List.append(sheet)

        print("Successfully appended the sheet" + p + "\n")

        Dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame()
        Dataframe1 = pd.concat(Empty_List)
        Dataframe1['Milestone'] = i
        Dataframe1.reset_index(inplace=False)

        write = ExcelWriter("inter"+str(i)+".xlsx")
        Dataframe1.to_excel(write, 'Sheet1', index=False)
        write.save()


        Dataframe_Temp = Allfields.append(Dataframe1)
        All_fields_Total_Columns = len(Allfields.columns)
        Dataframe_Total_columns = len(Dataframe_Temp.columns)

        if Dataframe_Total_columns == All_fields_Total_Columns:
            Milestone_Dataframe = Allfields.append(Dataframe1)

        else:
            print("Total number of columns are not same")
    All_Milestone = All_Milestone.append(Milestone_Dataframe)

write = ExcelWriter('Final.xlsx')
All_Milestone.to_excel(write, 'Sheet1', index=False)
write.save()
```

So can you please tell me how to accurately save the value of Milestone column.